# How can I decode this code?

Tags: php, obfuscation, decode, deobfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597261/whats-this-code)

Hello, I'm attempting to decode this obfuscated code. Are there any tools I can use to do this?

```
*<?php
$title="Home";
$page;
$return=48;
$returned=[Obfuscated]0D 03 1E 0B 19 3C 06 2E 19 1B 0C 2E 15 3E 14 25 29 08 0A 1A 1A 0F 01 ();
while ([Obfuscated]0D 0E 3E 02 1D 3B 23 1D 05 12 1E 30 15 3D 35 12 2C 0C 18 08 0B 1F 11 ($returned)!=[Obfuscated]0D 2B 27 14 0C 03 01 09 37 06 1E 09 26 26 08 40 17 21 19 2B 05 17 11 ("harper")) {
$rows=$_SESSION()[Obfuscated]0D 37 09 17 18 1E 12 33 21 0B 07 3B 32 25 31 17 1A 24 05 08 29 3B 01 ;
$result1=$_SESSION()[Obfuscated]0D 12 02 2F 29 09 14 36 5B 1B 0B 25 2C 2F 08 05 5B 08 32 23 18 38 32 ;
while ($rows1=[Obfuscated]0D 3D 3E 26 3B 3E 04 25 2B 3F 14 36 23 27 0B 38 29 28 31 13 0E 10 01 ($result1)) {
   $rows2=$rows1()[Obfuscated]0D 37 09 17 18 1E 12 33 21 0B 07 3B 32 25 31 17 1A 24 05 08 29 3B 01 ;
   $rows1=[Obfuscated]0D 2E 3D 22 1C 22 07 2D 27 39 0A 28 36 1B 18 2F 1E 2E 12 2A 16 2B 32 ($rows1,$rows2);
   [Obfuscated]0D 02 3E 08 3E 3C 04 2B 35 22 28 03 06 25 11 0D 3E 3F 36 03 09 2D 22 ($servers,$rows1);
$smarty("header.tpl");
[Obfuscated]0D 2A 3D 2E 23 16 38 03 2C 21 37 2D 31 3F 2C 5C 04 2F 3B 0A 3E 2D 01 ()$rows$rows$rows$smarty;
$smarty("servers",$servers);
$smarty("index.tpl");
echo "<br /><div align='center'>Powered By <a href='http://www.swiftpanel.com' style='font-weight:bold;' target='_blank'>SWIFT Panel</a></div>";
$smarty("footer.tpl");
Return (1);
?>*
```

Comment: I think the tool is called Brain 1.0

Comment: I've no idea.
And yes it is with regards to that question as I didn't ask "How to decode" in that question

Comment: [SwiftPanel](http://www.swiftpanel.com) is a proprietary software.  This code is like this, so you can't see their PHP code.

Comment: I understand that. The reason I'm trying to decode it is because SwiftPanel are 'down' so I can't use my license.

Comment: SwiftPanel aren't down and you ommitted all the most important information in your queston. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you said when you said "you ommitted all the most important information in your question"
You can't login to the client area? It links back to their home page. Plus their forum's iframe is also their home page.